# Thruk API : Not Found The requested URL /thruk/r/v1 was not found on this server

Tags: nagios, thruk

While trying to access thruk API on version 2.46.2 it errors out saying the below
Not Found
The requested URL /thruk/r/v1 was not found on this server.

Apache Server at ********.com Port 80

A valid output being returned when the API call is being made.

Comment: You need to provide more information. If the API calls are working, how do they differ from the HTTP requests made by your browser?

Comment: if the url /thruk/ works, then it's your apache configuration. Maybe because you updated from a previous version without the rest api and did not accept the changes to the apache config.